Поправьте, пожалуйста, запятые, если надо
Но понимала, что мы строим дом, и если хотим быстрее в него переехать, и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, нужны средства.

Но понимала, что мы строим дом, и если хотим быстрее в него переехать, и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, нужны средства. - несогласованность по времени.

Действительно так, несогласованность имеется. Я как-то не обратила внимание – у меня этот вариант просто никак не вписывался в правильную речь.

Пожалуйста:
Но понимала, что мы строим дом, и, если хотим быстрее в него переехать и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, нужны средства.
Сомневаюсь в запятой после "дом": что мы строим дом и что нужны средства,
тогда:
Но понимала, что мы строим дом и, если хотим быстрее в него переехать и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, нужны средства.
Но если второе "что" - додуманное мной - опустить, то первый вариант верен: нужны средства "если хотим быстрее в него переехать и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно".

Но понимала(кто?), что если мы(?) строим дом, если хотим быстрее в него переехать, чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, - нужны средства.

Выбираем вариант:
Но понимала, ЧТО (1) мы строим дом и (что) (2) ЕСЛИ хотим быстрее в него переехать и чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, ТО нужны средства.
Пояснение

Рассмотрим отдельно вторую часть сложного предложения:

...если хотим (что?) быстрее в него переехать и хотим (что?) чтобы там всё было сделано, всем было комфортно, то нужны средства. Здесь нестандартная связь: союз И связывает член предложения (хотим переехать) с придаточным цели (хотим ЧТОБЫ)

Части предложения (1) и (2) являются соподчинительными придаточными и составляют основную структуру предложения:   Но понимала, что строится дом и (что) если...то нужны средства.

Двойной союз если...то позволяет не ставить запятую после союза И пред второй частью, но прежде всего, такой союз однозначно задает основную структуру сложной синтаксической конструкции.


ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ (отзыв о предложении)
В предложении 6 предикативных основ.  Конечно, читатель догадается, о чем речь, хотя не вполне понятные подчинительные отношения и разнообразие  сочинительных и подчинительных союзов  задержат его внимание. Но в любом случае наличие вариантов прочтения вполне обоснованно будет считаться стилистическим недочетом.
В предложении с правильной грамматикой и хорошей стилистикой постановка знаков обычно не вызывает сомнения, и тогда не приходится думать, что же автор имел в виду.
